# Why do I see the timezone offset displayed in PgAdmin, for a timestamp with timezone

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, pgadmin, timezone, pgadmin-4

I'm using PgAdmin 4 v6, and for some timestamp data with data type of `timestamp with time zone`, I'm seeing it in PgAdmin like this:

`2022-03-06 16:11:33+04`

**Why is the `+04` being displayed?**

---

I've looked at the following postgres guide:

[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/datatype-datetime.html#:~:text=PostgreSQL%20assumes%20your%20local%20time,being%20displayed%20to%20the%20client](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/datatype-datetime.html#:%7E:text=PostgreSQL%20assumes%20your%20local%20time,being%20displayed%20to%20the%20client).

It states the following:

> All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They
> are converted to local time in the zone specified by the TimeZone
> configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.

The reference [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) states the following about TimeZone configuration in Postgres:

> `TimeZone (string)` Sets the time zone for displaying and interpreting
> time stamps. The built-in default is GMT, but that is typically
> overridden in postgresql.conf; initdb will install a setting there
> corresponding to its system environment.

This suggests that a timezone derived somehow from the database host system is being added to postgresql.conf.

I *assume* that the reason I see the offset in PgAdmin is that PgAdmin is displaying a converted version of the stored value, based on timezone info for the database host system, that's been stored in postgresql.conf. Can anyone confirm if this is what PgAdmin does when it  displays data with data type `timestamp with timezone`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm in Dublin - currently on UTC/GMT.

I did the following:

```
CREATE TABLE t 
(
  x TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL
);
```

then

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES (NOW());
```

Then in pgAdmin, I `SELECT * FROM t` and the value I see is

```
x
timestamp with timezone
2022-03-09 05:15:02.899933+00
```

Note the timezone: 2022-03-09 05:15:02.899933`+00` - because I'm on UTC/GMT.

Fine. I check my `postgresql.conf` and I have `timezone = 'Europe/Dublin'`.

To double check, I look at the command line:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names WHERE name = current_setting('TIMEZONE');
     name      | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst
---------------+--------+------------+--------
 Europe/Dublin | GMT    | 00:00:00   | t
(1 row)
```

So, belt and braces:

```
postgres=# SELECT name, setting, unit, short_desc FROM pg_settings WHERE setting  LIKE '%ublin%';
   name   |    setting    | unit |                           short_desc
----------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
 TimeZone | Europe/Dublin |      | Sets the time zone for displaying and interpreting time stamps.
(1 row)
```

Note the `short_desc` field:

```
Sets the time zone for displaying and interpreting time stamps.
```

Now, I edit my `postgresql.conf` and change the timezone to `America/Los_Angeles` and restart my server!

Now, if I do `SELECT * FROM t;` it gives me:

```
2022-03-08 21:15:02.899933-08
```

Compare this with `2022-03-09 05:15:02.899933+00` - they're the **same time** - just displayed differently - due **entirely** to my `postgresql.conf` setting!

Presumably this is so that the displayed times will be meaningful to those looking at them. People won't think they have appointments in the middle of the night &c. It can be easy to skip the timezone part of a displayed datetime/timestamp if one isn't used to them.

I can think of one example of where it might be a good idea to have the display **always** in UTC/Zulu and that is in civil aviation where all times are always given in Zulu (you'll frequently see YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`Z` written).

### Answer:

Yes, it is the `timezone` setting in `postgresql.conf` that determines the **display** of the time to you! The `TIMESTAMPTZ` **value** is immutable!

You say:

> I assume that the reason I see the offset in PgAdmin is that PgAdmin
> is displaying a converted version of the stored value, based on
> timezone info for the database host system, that's been stored in
> postgresql.conf. Can anyone confirm if this is what PgAdmin does when
> it displays data with data type timestamp with timezone?

When I installed Windows on this machine, I chose the timezone for the PC as `Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London` and when I installed PostgreSQL, the timezone in `postgresql.conf` was set to `Europe/London` - I reset it to `Europe/Dublin`. PostgreSQL obviously makes what it thinks is a best guess based on your system settings. However, as you can see from the above, it's easy to change this.